# Shared Preferences: How to save files name in a spinner

Tags: java, android

I'm making an app that can store disciplines grades.

First you can create a new discipline, choosing its name and placing your grade on that specific dicipline.

I'm using shared preferences to make that, the code is like this:

```
SharedPreferences disciplines = getSharedPreferences("Math", MODE_PRIVATE);  
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = disciplines.edit();  
prefEditor.putString("firstGrade", "80");
prefEditor.putString("secondGrade", "50" );
prefEditor.putString("thirdGrade", "65");
prefEditor.putString("fourthGrade", "25");
prefEditor.commit();
```

After that I want the user to be able to choose that discipline from a spinner in the main activity.

**How can I create a Spinner with this app Shared Preference files names?**

Like a spinner with "Math", and then "English", "Spanish" and other disciplines that he create.

Heres a image sample.[image: Heres a image sample]

Answer (score 0):

Though not an answer to your specific question, I believe you should rethink your strategy and use a [SQLite database](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) instead. SharedPreferences were really not made for the use case you're trying to tackle.